# Not able to write article after vertical menu in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write my article beside my vertical menu, but all my article going inside that menu. I want my menu to be fixed on that page on the left side and all my new articles or any pictures should come on after menu.

MY HTML

```
<nav id="wrapper-250">

    <ul class="accordion">

        <li id="one" class="files">

            <a href="#one">Health Beat</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Sub Menu 1</a>

                    <ul class="sub-sub-menu">

                        <li><a href="#"><em>a</em>Sub Menu 2</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#"><em>b</em>Sub Menu 2</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#"><em>c</em>Sub Menu 2</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#"><em>d</em>Sub Menu 2</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#"><em>e</em>Sub Menu 2</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Sub Menu 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Sub Menu 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Sub Menu 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Sub Menu 1</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li id="two" class="mail">

            <a href="#two">Mail</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Hotmail</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Yahoo</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li id="three" class="cloud">

            <a href="#three">Cloud</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Connect</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Profiles</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Options</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Connect</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Profiles</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>06</em>Options</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li id="four" class="sign">

            <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>


<div id="body-part">
    <p>
    </P>

</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbXbqQ

Comment: Can you also put your CSS here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a big padding-left to your `#body-part`:

```
  padding-left: 500px; /* example */
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/baLq1d1k/

Or you can do it using jquery if the `width` of your `#wrapper-250` changes:

```
$("#body-part").css("padding-left", ($("#wrapper-250").width() + 10));
```

Comment: i can also do that by making #body-part to float right but if i see in mobile version or just using width 20% and 80% , why its not working

Comment: Because, the width of your container is too large, and it doesn't have the right espace to float to the right!